# Download a file using qwebkit

Tags: pyqt4, qwebkit

Good day to all. I started using X. I don't want to surf websites only, but download files too. What should I add to the code, to let it just download the file in a directory without any dialog window.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import os, sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qwv = QWebView() 
    qwv.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://google.com"))
    qwv.show()
    app.exec_()
```

ps. I want that to when you click on the link "download the file" on any sites the file is loading in local folder, but when you click on the "regural" link the qwebkit is opening this page.

Answer (score 0):

To download a file you could use [`urllib.urlretrieve()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib#urllib.urlretrieve):

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

To download links that QWebView can't show:

```
qwv.page().setForwardUnsupportedContent(True)
qwv.page().unsupportedContent.connect(save_file_callback)
```

Comment: No, I want that to when you click on the link "download the file" on any sites the file is loading in local folder, but when you click on the "regural" link the qwebkit is opening this page.